# Зачем лочить эталонные вопросы по литературе?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Вроде давать на них лишние ответы и так никто не рвётся, а из-за лока теряется возможность за них голосовать и вносить правки. Точно ли такая блокировка имеет смысл?

> заблокирован пользователем Nick Volynkin♦ вчера
>
> Ответы на данный вопрос даны совместными усилиями: если вы считаете, что можно что-то улучшить, просто внесите правки в ответ! Добавлять ответы здесь нельзя

На мой взгляд, обычной блокировки от новичков (где надо +10) было вполне достаточно.

Comment: внезапно, блокировка этого вида разрешает голосовать за ответы, но запрещает голосовать за вопросы (хотя кнопки видны на UI). больше похоже на баг, но пока стоит поменять тип блокировки

Comment: @PashaPash Я не понял, так какая блокировка была на вопросе? По истории https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/454683/revisions непонятно. И таки этот вопрос должен быть общественно-заблокирован, а не защищён, потому что новые ответы там совершенно не нужны.

Comment: @Discord есть более мягкий, чем исторический, вид блокировки. он запрещает добавление новых ответов, но разрешает правку существующих. Т.е. он задуман именно для CW. Но в текущем виде он как-то кривоват. Попрошу Николаса написать девам, вдруг что-то узнает.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну я и говорю про "общественную блокировку". Пока из ответа Ника снизу я понял, что единственная проблема — это невозможность поставить плюсик на вопросе. Ну просто ужас какая потеря для вопросов, которые на сайте запрещено задавать.

Comment: Вся эта "мышиная возня" с "повышением качества" сайта просто бесполезна, а по большому счету скорее вредна. Она не просто отвлекает от основной цели -- *ответы на вопрос*, а отвращает (по крайней мере меня, но подозреваю, что и значительное число ранее активных участников (например посмотрите, сколько из них вообще приняли участие в выборах)) от этого сайта.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не могли бы вы привести несколько примеров вопросов, где вы не можете голосовать?

Answer (score 4):

Этот лок судя по описанию сделан как раз для таких вопросов. Именно описанием мы руководствовались при расстановке локов.

У него есть следующие полезные свойства:

- Позволяет голосовать за ответ(ы)
- Позволяет редактировать ответ(ы)
- Не позволяет давать новые ответы.

Но, неожиданно:

- Не позволяет голосовать за вопрос
- Не позволяет редактировать вопрос

Как-то мы не заметили этих особенностей, придется снять локи. В ближайшее время обсудим в широком кругу, что делать с локами на списках литературы, нужны ли они вообще.

Comment: Недоступность редактирования вопроса — это нормально. А ради одного голосования за вопросы снимать блокировку и терять все три полезных свойства — это странно. "Защита" ни от чего не защитит, она бесполезна.

Comment: @Discord: я тоже не вижу большого смысла в голосах, которые по определению не приносят репутации. Разве что вопрос поднимают в топе и баджи приносят, но это мелочи.

Comment: Разве при поиске голоса не учитываются?

Comment: @Qwertiy: за ответы всегда голосуют больше, чем за ответы. Поэтому в топе по метке будет находиться ответ, который продолжает получать голоса.

Comment: А автопоиск при создании темы что ищет - вопросы или ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy конечно вопросы. Алгоритм поиска мне неизвестен, но я бы поднимал вопросы с наплюсованными ответами.