# Пометить вики-вопросы с предполагаемым единственным ответом нужным статусом

Tags: предложение, общие-сообщения

В вопросе [Не переведена плашка на общих вопросах (community effort)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9998/176217) выяснилось, что у нас существуют вопросы (в основном всякие сборники литературы), которые концептуально должны иметь один единственный редактируемый вики-ответ, но пока ещё допускают публикацию новых ответов.

Моё предложение в том, чтобы модераторы пометили их подходящим признаком для отображения новой плашки:

> [image: плашка совместных усилий]

Список подобных вопросов можно получить поиском на сайте по такому запросу: [`wiki:1 is:q answers:1`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3A1%20is%3Aq%20answers%3A1). Сейчас там 30 совпадений, но некоторые из них всё же не подпадают под критерий "community effort" и, конечно, их помечать не стоит.

Comment: Вот тут было предложение не лочить: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2272/178988

Answer (score 5):

Такая блокировка не даст голосовать за вопрос (не помню, вместе с ответами или нет), поэтому лично я против её применения.

Comment: Любопытно. За вопрос действительно голосовать нельзя. Но за ответы можно. Довольно странный, конечно, момент.

Comment: Гм. Действительно :( А я уже штук десять нашлёпал блокировок утром.

Comment: @AK, вроде ж уже раньше обсуждали?

Comment: На метамету не писал кто-нибудь фичреквест об этом?

Comment: @andreymal, вроде только на нашей было: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2272/178988

Comment: @andreymal [написал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346955/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, уже закрыли.

Comment: @Qwertiy но ДУБЛИКАТОМ! Правда, старый пост аж 8+ лет давности. Так что, скорее всего, дело труба. С другой стороны - мы все давно уже знаем, что ожидать исполнения реализации фич на SO довольно наивно.